# problems with rendering a list of items in react native

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using react-native 0.73.2 with expo 50.0.4 on Android, and I am rendering the list of a shopping cart with the FlatList component of react-native and when removing the second to last product it does not render the last remaining product in the list (for more clarity see the video), as you can see the product is still preserved in the list and the `EmptyItems` component is not shown either. I am new to this and it is difficult for me to understand this type of behavior.

**My code**

```
export const CartList = () => {
  const { cart } = useCartStoreHandler()
  console.log('Cart length: ', cart.length);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={cart}
      className="flex-1 bg-red-200"
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ListEmptyComponent={EmptyItems}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Text className="w-full mb-4 border-b-[1px] border-gray-300"> </Text>}
      renderItem={({ item }: { item: ProductCart }) => <CartItem product={item} />}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id_producto.toString()}
    />
  )
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyMig.gif)